# How to prevent data input for being erase in Grails with reCaptcha

Tags: grails, recaptcha, gsp

I have gsp with two textfield for firstname-lastname and reCaptcha. What I want is for every wrong captcha code the user's input for firstname and last name won't be erased.

snippet for controller:

```
       ***captcha_code****
       if (result) {
        def person = new Person(params)
        person.save()
        render "Success!"
    } else {
        flash.message = message(code: 'forgotPassword.captcha.wrong')
        redirect(controller:'person', action:'form')
    }
```

snipper for form.gsp

```
***captcha_code_here***
<g:form controller="person" action="save">
<label>First Name: </label>
<g:textField name="firstName"/><br/>
<label>Last Name: </label>
<g:textField name="lastName"/><br/>
<g:if test="${flash.message}">
    <div class="message" role="status" style="font-size: medium;color: green;">${flash.message}</div>
</g:if>
***captcha_code_here***
<g:actionSubmit value="Save"/>
```

Comment: So you should send firstname and lastname back after unsuccessfull checking recaptcha. Show your controller and view codes.

Comment: please check my edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To repopulate the fields you can use the same `flash` scope you're using for the message. On error, add the first and last name to the `flash` scope, and then in your GSP use those values when they are available:

### PersonController

```
class PersonController {
    def save() {
        ...

        if(/* recaptcha failed */) {
            flash.firstName = params.firstName
            flash.lastName = params.lastName
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

### GSP

```
<label>First Name: </label>
<g:textField name="firstName" value="${flash.firstName ?: ''}"/><br/>
<label>Last Name: </label>
<g:textField name="lastName" value="${flash.lastName ?: ''}"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Controller Action, send back fields that you want to be repopulated.